# Installing Packages Offline with Pip, but for some reason it will not recognize a wheel?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I'm trying to make a script to install python packages offline. Here's what I've done:

1. Uninstall Python and delete old Python 2.7 folder on C:
2. Install clean copy of Python 2.7.16
3. Install all required packages via pip install (with internet connection) like normal
4. In command prompt, navigate to the folder I am going to put my wheels into and do pip freeze -> requirements.txt
5. Do pip download -r requirements.txt
6. Uninstall python, delete Python 2.7 again, install python, test script

My script is literally: python -m pip install --no-index --find-links . -r requirements.txt

It is installing packages normally, until it hits cffi. For some reason, it does not recognize this package even though it is in the folder. In the folder, its name is cffi-1.12.2-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl. In the requirements file, it's listed as cffi==1.12.2. They're the same version, so I'm not quite sure what is causing this, and I couldn't really find any questions with a similar problem where it was just one package and all the versions and procedure was similar. If someone could steer me in the right direction, that would be great. Thank you! All I can think is to install it explicitly at the beginning of the script, but I really don't want to have to do it that way if I can avoid it (in case I run into that issue with other packages later).

Comment: You probably have a 64bit windows; check it by running `python -c "from pip._internal import pep425tags; print(pep425tags.get_platform())"`. The wheel you downloaded is for 32bit windows.

Comment: @hoefling you were right. I was switching between the two because of some of the packages and as a result they were mixed up. Thank you so much.